# facebook like hashtags - word-wrap:break-word; doesnt work on FF and IE9+

Tags: jquery, css, facebook

I'm trying to insert a `<b>` whenever on `keyup`, a `#` is detected (like `Facebook`). I read from the `textarea`, and copy to a `div` element.

```
    <div  class="new_postAdDescription2" id="new_postAdDescription2" spellcheck='false' contenteditable='true'> </div>  
    <textarea name="description" id="new_postAdDescription" spellcheck='false' 
class="new_postAdDescription" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Posto nj&euml; shpallje" >
</textarea>
```

Please see how I replace white spaces and new lines. I have tried `&nbsp;` as well (btw here, if I remove white space matching, everything works fine!)

```
$('#new_postAdDescription').keyup(function (e) {
        var str = $('#new_postAdDescription').val();

        str = str.replace(/ /g, '&#160;');
        str = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br/> ');

        str = str.replace(/(&#160;|<br\/> )#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g, "$1<b class='highlighterContent'>#$2</b>");

        $('#new_postAdDescription2').html(str);  
    });
```

// Style

```
<style>
.new_postAdDescription, .new_postAdDescription2{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    outline: 0;
    width: 694px;
    color:#1c1c1c;
    resize: none;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 115px;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:1.3;
    direction: ltr; 
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

.new_postAdDescription2{
position:absolute;
color:transparent;
word-wrap:break-word;
direction: ltr; 
text-align: left;
}
.highlighterContent{
position:relative;
font-weight:bold;
color:#333;
background-color:#f2f2f2;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

</style>
```

It's not the best, but it works fine with Chrome, but on FF and IE9, when it comes to breaking the word, it overlaps text and loses track. see screen shot

in `FF` and `IE9`

[image]

while in `Chrome`:

[image]

Comment: If I am not wrong than you need some thing like When user use '#' with some word it will start highlighting those word ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did figure it out the right answer....

the new javascript is (much simpler):

```
$('#new_postAdDescription').keyup(function (e) {
    var str =$('#new_postAdDescription').val();

    str = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    str = str.replace(/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g, "<b>#$1</b>");

    $('#new_postAdDescription2').html(str);
});
```

and the in css:

```
.new_postAdDescription, .new_postAdDescription2{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    width: 694px;
    resize: none;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 115px;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:1.3;
    direction: ltr;
    color:#1c1c1c;
}

.new_postAdDescription2{
    position:absolute;
    color:transparent;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
b{
font-weight:bold;
color:#333;
display: inline-block;
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap:break-word;
direction: ltr; 
text-align: left;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

adding white-space: pre-wrap; at the right place made it work.